# Reusing generated classes from included XSDs

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have 6 XSD files all of which have these lines to import/include 3 further XSD files (I did not write them, I just need to use them):-

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="ORIGOMESSAGEHEADER.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="ORIGODATATYPELIBRARY.xsd"/>
```

The 6 XSD files all need to be in different (C#) namespaces (because they use the same top-level type names) but that then means I get 6 copies of the types from the ORIGO* XSDs. This is very frustrating because I would need to duplicate lots of code for each duplicate type (or add interfaces for them all).

Is there any way of generating C# classes for the 6 main XSDs which will use a single, shared copy of classes generated from the ORIGO*.XSD types?

I tried using XSD2CODE with the ExcludeImportedTypes option but got an error: 
"Error: Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema." - no idea what that means.

(The XSD are not secret so I can upload a zip file containing all 9 if that helps)

Comment: Give `ORIGOMESSAGEHEADER.xsd` and `ORIGODATATYPELIBRARY.xsd` their own namespaces and import them rather than include them.

Comment: OK, so then I would have to define an "xmlns:origo" attribute in my 6 XSDs and then modify usages of the types to use that?

Comment: Sigh! This seems to add XmlElement(Namespace="www.origo.com") attributes which, unless I'm mistaken, will result in namespaces in the final XML which I don't want.

Comment: Don't try to create no-namespace XML.  The namespace of an element is a core part of its specification, and the tools you work with will all expect it. Instead, create single namespace XML by using the same targetNamespace throughout your xsd.  If you *really* don't want that namespace in your serialized output/input, then hold your nose and pre-process and post-process the file as an additional step.

Comment: Thanks Eric but I have no control over the XSDs or the namespace-less XML files I will receive - they are just given to me by the service provider. I guess I will just have to write a lot of duplicate code.